# Side Menu issue in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my ionic menu, if we click any page from menu list, side menu appears. But on button click if we load any page side menu does not appear untill we refresh

Answer (score 0):

I also face same type of problem,i think its help you.

I forgot to use the option **enable-menu-with-back-views="true"** on my `<ion-side-menus>`

Comment: But this disapppears once we refresh. Have you noticed that?